How can I update the UI immediately after adding a new todo in my MERN app without refreshing the page?
Body: I’m working on a MERN stack todo app and am facing an issue where the newly added todo doesn't immediately appear in the UI. The new todo only shows up after I refresh the page.
Issue:
After adding a new todo by clicking the "Add" button, the todo does not appear in the UI unless I manually refresh the page. I am using setTodos to update the state in the TodoContext, but the newly added todo doesn't reflect in the UI immediately.
Expected Behavior:
I want the newly added todo to show up in the UI immediately after clicking the "Add" button, without requiring a page refresh.
const TodoContext = createContext();

export const TodoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = async (title) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/todos/addTodo', { title });
      // Updating the state with the newly added todo
      setTodos((prev) => [...prev, response.data.data]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ todos, addTodos }}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
};


const Add = () => {
  const { addTodos } = useTodo();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleAdd = async () => {
    if (input.trim()) {
      await addTodos(input);  // Adding new todo
      setInput("");  // Resetting input field
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>;
};

const Read = () => {
  const { todos } = useTodo();

  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <div key={todo._id}>{todo.title}</div>  // Displaying todos
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


Welcome to Stackoverflow. could you provide the missing code for useTodo and the view where you're putting together Read and Add under a TodoProvider ?

I see that you update the todos state with setTodos((prev) => [...prev, response.data.data]);. What is the value of response.data.data? Is it not the new todo? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and provide any debugging details.

The reason for this behavior is that the state update you're making with setTodos is not being reflected in the UI immediately. This is because React's state updates are asynchronous, and the UI re-rendering happens after the state has been updated.
To fix this issue and make the newly added todo appear in the UI immediately, you can use the following approach:
Optimistic UI Update:
Instead of waiting for the API response to update the state, you can update the state optimistically, i.e., immediately after the user clicks the "Add" button. This will make the new todo appear in the UI right away, and then you can update the state with the actual data from the API response.


const TodoContext = createContext();

export const TodoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = async (title) => {
    try {
      setTodos((prev) => [...prev, { _id: Math.random().toString(), title, completed: false }]);

      const response = await axios.post('/api/todos/addTodo', { title });
      // update with actual one
      setTodos((prev) =>
        prev.map((todo) =>
          todo._id === response.data.data._id ? response.data.data : todo
        )
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // revert the change if it fails
      setTodos((prev) => prev.filter((todo) => todo._id !== response.data.data._id));
    }
  };

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ todos, addTodos }}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Add = () => {
  const { addTodos } = useTodo();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleAdd = async () => {
    if (input.trim()) {
      await addTodos(input);
      setInput("");
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>;
};

const Read = () => {
  const { todos } = useTodo();

  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo._id}>{todo.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};



